# Is it more efficient to store XML in a SQL database record or in XML files?

Tags: sql, xml

Is it more efficient to store the XML file paths and reference them through the database or to just put the XML straight into it's own database record?

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Here's my scenario.
I'm creating a CE Sql server database with code in a c# Windows Application.
It's a Fantasy Football Application.  When a user selects a player, it'll add a node containing the player_id and information to the Team's XML.

The UserTeam table would look like this..

(UserTeam_ID, User_ID, xml_team_data)

When I say efficient, I guess I mean what would be a better practice.  Less code, better load time

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do with them... if you want to associate them with searchable data or just serve them on a fixed path from a web server for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL (at least SQL Server) will store the XML files as blobs, so in binary format. Aparently you can do operations on the XML stored there, look at the link in the comment.

If you don't plan to access XML parts from inside the db, it is better to hold your files separately on the file system and just point to them from the DB. If you decide later to use a cloud based system like Azure, you will be charged by database size, and you don't want that to be too big.

Comment: Actually, there's [quite a lot](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/27/sql-server-introduction-to-discovering-xml-data-type-methods-a-primer/) you can do with XML at the database level in SQL server.